# Get checkbox value in a javascript function

Tags: javascript, c#-4.0, html-parsing

I'm doing javascript injection, below is my code.

```
HtmlElement head = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("head")[0];
HtmlElement scriptEl = webBrowser1.Document.CreateElement("script");
IHTMLScriptElement element = (IHTMLScriptElement)scriptEl.DomElement;

element.text = "function sayHello() { debugger; alert('Helloooo');" + " var resume=webBrowser1.Document.GetElementByTagName('resID');" +
               " var i; for (i=0;i<resume.length;i++){if (resume[i].checked){alert(\"hi....\");} }  }";

head.AppendChild(scriptEl);
System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("html: {0}",head.InnerHtml);
webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("sayHello");`
```

My check box name is resID. The statement after alert in sayHello function is not executing. The result of this code is , its giving alert as Hello and its stopping execute. Is there any mistake in my code while accessing check box value.  I

Comment: You need to format this if you expect people to answer.

Comment: Using `webBrowser1.Document.getElementsByTagName` within a script *executed in the browser* isnt going to work as it has no idea what `webBrowser1` is; its only a valid identifer withing the scope of the C# code. `document.getElementsByTagName` will work.

Comment: When you want formatted code, just put a blank line between your last line of text and the first line of the code that you indent four spaces. Otherwise it wont color. Only use the backtick ` if you want code `in the middle` of a line of text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change the line.

```
var resume=webBrowser1.Document.GetElementByTagName('resID');
```

to

```
var resume=document.getElementByTagName('resID');
```